# Sorting custom (currency) formatted column in backgrid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I'm using Backgridjs to display data from json object to table. I'm currently using a formatter to format string-numbers into currency. Once I did that the sorting no longer work properly as it sorting as a string rather than number. How can I enable sorting with backgrid after formatting my column ?

Backgrid support numbers, int, date/momentjs. Couldn't find extension for currency

this is my formatter class

```
formatter: _.extend({}, Backgrid.CellFormatter.prototype, {
    fromRaw: function(rawData) {
      var re = /\-/;
      if (rawData === "" || rawData == null) {
        return "";
      } else if (rawData.match(re)) {
        return "-" + accounting.formatMoney(rawData.substr(1));
      } else {
        return accounting.formatMoney(rawData);
      }
    },
    toRaw: function(formattedData) {
      return formattedData;
    }


  }),
```

And this is my grid

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
collection: collection,
columns: [
{
  name: "cost",
  label: "Cost",
  cell: "number",
  formatter: currencyFormater 
  sortable: true
},
{
  name: "type",
  label: "Type",
  cell: Backgrid.NumberCell,
  sortable: true
}
]});
```

Example of data:

```
{ id: 1, cost: "150", type: 3 },
{ id: 2, cost: "12516.30", type: 2 },
{ id: 3, cost: "21400.85", type: 1 },
{ id: 4, cost: "146558.50", type: 1 },
{ id: 5, cost: "139982.75", type: 1 }
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping the value as number and simply showing currency symbol next to it using css pseudo elements?

Comment: Hi @TJ, that would be great. But I'm getting the data as string and the problem is with the point (fraction of in the number) they wouldn't be formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using sortValue to do specific sorting base on value. In my case I used parseFloat with the string value.

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
collection: collection,
columns: [
 {
   name: "cost",
   label: "Cost",
   cell: "number",
   sortValue: function(model) {
     return parseFloat(model.get("cost"));
 },
 formatter: currencyFormater 
 sortable: true
 },
 …
]});
```